# Can the numbers of elements of distinct prime orders of a finite simple group coincide?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Does there exist a finite simple group $G$ and distinct prime numbers
$p$ and $q$ dividing the order of $G$ such that the numbers of elements
of $G$ of order $p$ and $q$ are the same?

*Remark 1:* It has been conjectured in

L. Jafari Taghvasani, M. Zarrin: 
  [A characterization of ${\rm A}_5$ by its Same-order type](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00605-016-0950-9), 
  Monatsh. Math. 182, No. 3, 731-736 (2017)

that the answer is *no* -- cf. Conjecture 2.10.

*Remark 2:* When leaving away the condition that the group is simple,
it is not difficult to see that the answer is *yes* -- see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49776/).

Comment: If $G = \operatorname{PSL}(2,11)$, then $G$ has $110$ elements of order $3$ and also $110$ elements of order $6$. So the conjecture fails without the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are prime.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen Yes, there are lots and lots such examples. -- The assumption that $p$ and $q$ are prime is (*very*) essential.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, indeed -- up to that there are in fact $136$ Sylow $3$-subgroups and $136$ Sylow $5$-subgroups in ${\rm SL}(2,16)$.

Comment: @StefanKohl : Corrected (slight oversight):As you are probably aware, examples like SL(2,2^n) are often "near misses", where the number of Sylow p-subgroups and Sylow q-subgroups are the same. For example, in SL(2,16), there are 136 Sylow 3-subgroups and 136 Sylow 5-subgroups (so there are exactly twice as many elements of order 5 as there are elements of order 3)

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Such examples are indeed quite frequent. It even happens that for some groups, the numbers of Sylow subgroups for several different primes coincide. -- For example, the numbers of Sylow $3$-subgroups, Sylow $5$-subgroups and Sylow $17$-subgroups of ${\rm PSL}(2,1021)$ are all equal to $521731$, and also the numbers of Sylow $7$-subgroups and Sylow $73$-subgrouos of that same group are both equal to $520710$.

Comment: Yes, I understand the general picture, and that SL(2,2^n) is just one example - there are lots of other examples of TI Hall subgroups of simple groups such that all of their Sylow subgroups have the same normalizer.

Comment: Nice question. I presume you've checked the sporadics? For $Alt(n)$, the number of elements of order $p$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\rfloor} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-(ip-1))}{p^i\cdot i!}$. I can't see an easy way to conclude that different $p$ and $q$ yield different values, although it seems likely...

Comment: Moser & Wyman have asymptotics for the number of $p$-elements in $Alt(n)$ for large $n$. If I understand correctly, their results imply that, for fixed $p$ and $q$, there will be a finite number of $n$ such that $Alt(n)$ has the same number of elements of order $p$ and $q$. It may be that they imply this if one just fixes $p$ (and allow both $q$ and $n$ to vary).

Comment: @NickGill Thanks for your comments! -- I have checked so far all simple groups of order less than 20000000, and many further groups - including the sporadics of order up to $|{\rm Suz}|$.

Comment: This question has been asked again here -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397324/finite-simple-groups-with-the-same-numbers-of-elements-of-orders-p-and-q -- and there is a partial answer... Should one of these questions be closed?

Comment: @NickGill Thanks for pointing this out. -- I closed this one, since the other has a (very partial) answer.